# Preenchendo input mascarado com zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou usando o plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ para criar mascara em um campo input, a mascara que estou usando é a seguinte.

```
$('.campo').mask('0.0.00.000');
```

Eu preciso que ao digitar os números em meu campo o valor referente a mascara seja preenchido com 0 no mesmo, ex:

```
1.0.23.000
```

Neste exemplo todos os valores iniciais do input são 0.0.00.000 e ao digitar os 0 seriam preenchidos pelo meu valor, caso eu removesse o zero voltaria a aparecer naquela posição.

Alguém teria alguma solução para este problema? O uso de plugins é opcional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando apenas JavaScript

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function(){
  return this.split('').reverse().join(''); 
};

function mascara(campo,evento){
  var tecla = (!evento) ? window.event.keyCode : evento.which;
  var valor = campo.value.replace(/[^\d]+/gi,'').reverse();
  var resultado = "";
  var mascara = "#.#.##.###".reverse();
  for (var x=0, y=0; x<mascara.length && y<valor.length;) {
    if (mascara.charAt(x) != '#') {
      resultado += mascara.charAt(x);
      x++;
    } else {
      resultado += valor.charAt(y);
      y++;
      x++;
    }
  }
  campo.value = resultado.reverse();
}
```

```html
<input type="Text" size="10" onKeyUp="mascara(this, event)"  value="">
```

Comment: Não entendi exatamente o que deseja, caso esse exemplo não sirva, explique melhor por favor.